# How to loop over directories and rename files?

Tags: python

Im ney to python and therefore apologize for the triviality of my question:

I have the following file structure, where a `.csv` file with employee is saved on daily basis:

```
dir/2012-01-01/employee.csv.bz2
dir/2012-01-02/employee.csv.bz2
dir/2012-01-03/employee.csv.bz2
dir/2012-01-04/employee.csv.bz2
dir/2012-01-05/employee.csv.bz2
```

I would like to go through each file and rename it. Afterwards I would like to save the new files in one common directory `dir/common`. What I tried:

```
import sys
import os


path = 'dir/'

for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        infilename = os.path.join(path, filename)
        newname = infilename.replace('.csv.bz2', '.csv')
        output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
```

But I get the error:

```
output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:   'dir/employee.csv.bz2' -> 'dir/employee.csv'
```

Not sure what Im doing wrong.

Comment: What happend if you tap `ls dir/employee.csv.bz2` on Terminal ?

Comment: The folder `dir/employee.csv.bz2`, doesn't exist. You're missing the subfolder in the path! Try adding the date folder!

Comment: use `folderName` instead of `path`in `os.path.join(path, filename)`  because `folderName` will have all subfolders when you go to subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `folderName` instead of `path` in `os.path.join(path, filename)` because `folderName` has full path to subfolder.

```
infilename = os.path.join(folderName, filename)
```

---

If you want to save in one folder then use this folder in `newname` and `rename()` will move file to new place.

```
newname = os.path.join('dir', 'common', filename.replace('.csv.bz2', '.csv'))
```

BTW: But you have to create this folder first.

```
os.mkdir('dir/common')
```

or to create folder and all intermediate folders from path

```
os.makedirs('dir/common/many/sub/folders/to/create')
```

Comment: Thank you.! How dow I add a staement to save the output files in one common folder?

Comment: `rename()` moves file if you use different folder in new name - ie. `new_file = os.path.join('dir', 'common', filename.replace('.csv.bz2', '.csv'))`

Comment: It saves just the first emploeyy into common

Comment: output = os.rename(infilename, newname)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists 'dir/2012-01-01\\employee.csv.bz2' -> 'dir/common\\employee.csv'

Answer (score 0):

`infilename = os.path.join(path, filename)`

You are missing the subfolder, which is evident from the error message: `'dir/employee.csv.bz2'`.